# Button isn't clicked in a keydown event

Tags: javascript, php, dom-events

[phptester.net](http://phptester.net) is a site that let's you test PHP codes online. You write the PHP code in a dedicated box, and then click a button with the text "Click to test your PHP code" and the result will appear in a adjacent box.

Testing each change with the keyboard is faster and more convenient to me, so I tried this code to do it by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', (event)=>{
  if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode === 65) {
    document.querySelector('.actionItem button').click();
  }
});
```

The code fails for some reason --- I mean, I could fill in some PHP code, and hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> but the button won't be clicked. Each time I hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> there are no errors in the console, so I don't know what to do with it.

This is the PHP code I used:

```
<?php
    $a=5;
    $b=10;
    if ($a < $b) {
        echo "$a is smaller than $b";   
    } else {
        echo "$a IS NOT smaller than $b";   
    }
?>
```

Comment: whats say console error?

Comment: There are no console errors when I hit `CTRL+A`.

Comment: Opps... I am reading wrong, sorry. Can u share full code? like `.actionItem button`

Comment: I really shared all the code I've tried whatsoever on this site...

Comment: `document.querySelector('.actionItem button').click();` Where is your button ?

Comment: I am not sure how useful it would be for you, but this code achieves the results of clicking the `Click to test your code` button - `$("#show-result").submit();`

Comment: keyCode is depreciated. You should use 'keypress' for your event handler and use event.code or event.key in your conditional: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode

Comment: I could not reconcile "javascript" and "php" code.

Answer (score 1):

You got the wrong querySelector, the following works for me:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', (event)=>{
  if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode === 65) {
    document.querySelector('.actionItem input.cbutton').click();
  }
});
```